# Smooth curves that are submanifolds

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $f:I\subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth function ($I$ is an interval in $\mathbb{R}$). What are the sufficient conditions (or sufficient and necessary) under which the image of this function (say $S$ which is indeed a curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$) is a submanifold? Is there any famous theorem on this topic?

---

---

I tried to find such conditions in this way: according to the definition of submanifold, we need a 1-dimensional submanifold chart for $S$ at every point $x$ of $S$. Thus, there should exist open interval $W \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and smooth function $G: W \to \mathbb{R}^n$. We need $G(W)=U \cap S$ where $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set and $x\in S \cap U$. Finally, we need the function $G$ to have the form $G(w)=A\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
w\\
g(w)
\end{array}} \right)$ where $A$ is non-singular and $g:W\to\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is a smooth function (I used the definition from *"Ordinary Differential Equations with Applications by C. Chicone"*).

I think the sufficient condition is that $f$ should be a diffeomorphism (it should be smooth and have smooth inverse) and $I$ be an open interval. Actually, in this case, the function $f$ plays the role of the function $G$ in the definition of submanifold.

Thank you, in advance, for your help!

Incidentally, I do not understand why we need $U$ in the definition of submanifold to be open? I am saying this because $S$ can be a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and thus $U\cap S $ may not be open. Indeed, my question is that whay the image of $W$ under $G$ i.e., $G(W)=U \cap S$, is always open?

Thanks.

Comment: A homeomorphism that is smooth and has a smooth inverse is called a *diffeomorphism*.  If $n>1$ then $f$ cannot be a homeomorphism onto $\mathbb{R}^n$ (from the context I guess that you mean that "$f$ is a *diffeomorphism onto its image*; yes, then it is a sufficient condition).

Comment: @user539887. Thank you for your comment. I revised it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean "embedded submanifolds" here? We say $M$ is an embedded submanifold of $N$ (where $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds) if some $f\colon M\to N$ is a smooth immersion and a topological embedding, i.e., if $df_p$ is nonsingular for each $p\in M$ and $f\colon M\to f(M)$ is a homeomorphism.

Now take $M=I$ (an interval in $\mathbb R$) and $N=\mathbb R^n$. In this case $df_p$ being nonsingular for each $p\in I$ means that $(\frac{df_1}{dt},\cdots,\frac{df_n}{dt})\neq 0$ at each $t\in I$, where $f=(f_1,\cdots,f_n)$ with $f_i\colon I\to \mathbb R$ smooth.

As for why you need open $U\subset \mathbb R^n$, the requirement that $f$ being a topological embedding addresses it. Note that if $f\colon I\to f(I)=S$ is a homeomorphism while $S$ inherits the topology from $\mathbb R^n$, then each open subset $V$ of $I$ is carried into an open subset $U\cap S$ of $S$, where $U\subset\mathbb R^n$ is open.

ps. If you let $f$ be a homeomorphism it's okay but this case forces $n=1$, which is trivial. I would recommend you to have a look over Frank W. Warner's *Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups*, which is quite a good resource to learn differentiable manifolds quickly.

Comment: Thank you very much. Honestly, I am not familiar with "embedded submanifolds" (I read your explanations and it is now more clear to me). In the *Chicone*'s book, the concept of manifolds is not discussed in details. It only provides the definition of *submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$*.

Anyway, your response was very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @ josephz: I am trying to check this solution using different curves. Consider $t \to (1-t^2,t-t^3)$ for $t \in (-\infty,1) $. We observe that this function is injective and the derivative does not vanish. However, it seems that the function is not a homeomorphism. I appreciate it if you let me know why it is the case? Thanks.

Comment: @Arthur This is the case of an "immersed submanifold". If we denote this map by $f$, note that any neighborhood of $(0,0)$ of this curve is not connected and $f$ will not map neighborhoods of $-1$ to neighborhoods of $(0,0)$. Thus $f$ is indeed not a homeomorphism onto its image. Actually you have formulated a case in p.23 of the book I mentioned in my answer. You can see the case more intuitively by plotting it, e.g. (although this plot is for $t\in(-\infty,+\infty)$, it is easy to find the corresponding part of $(-\infty, 1)$) http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2-y%5E2-x%5E3%3D0

Comment: @ josephz: Thank you very much for your response. So the problem with this example is that we cannot find any open neighborhood of the origin s.t. it will be the graph of a smooth function.

Comment: @Arthur To refute $f\colon I=(-\infty,1)\to f(I),\ t\mapsto (1-t^2,t-t^3)$ being a homeomorphism, we just to show that $f$ is not an open map. Namely some open subset of $I$ will not be mapped to an open subset of $f(I)$. Now open balls containing $-1\in I$ is carried to connected subsets containing $(0,0)\in f(I)$, while any open ball (small enough) containing $(0,0)$ is disconnected. So the image any open ball (small enough) containing $-1$ is not open. ps. some neighborhood of $-1$ is indeed mapped to a neighborhood of $(0,0)$, e.g. $I$ itself. I think you mean "image" instead of "graph"?

Comment: @ josephz: You are totally right. But In my comment, I mean "graph", because roughly speaking, submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$ should be *the graph of a smooth function defined on an open subset* (permutation of variables should also be considered). I am referring to Definition 1.87 of "Ordinary Differential Equations with Applications by C. Chicone". Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Arthur It should be Definition 1.78 of your quoted book I guess. Also, yes locally a submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$ can be perceived so.

Comment: @ josephz: Yes, sorry for the typo. It is Def. 1.78. Thanks!